# Python search string contains characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-manipulation, python-re

I have a data below:

```
col1      
086945159
549615853
589ac2546
GED456231
F56hy8W12
```

I want to find whether `col` has non-numeric value and return.

```
col1         col2 
086945159    086945159
549615853    549615853
589ac2546    Nan
GED456231    Nan
F56hy8W12    Nan
111111111    Nan
222222222    Nan
```

I used `re.search(r'[^0-9]+', str)` to find. However, how can I use this in `apply()` since if value in `col` has the same number, like `11111111` and `222222222`, this should return `Nan`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't check if the string consists of the same values with regular expressions. So I'd suggest replacing it with `nan` afterward.

Comment: Hi! I'm sure the community can help you with this.  But first, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), How to Ask, and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: you can check if len(set(string.split())) == 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mask` with conditional pattern:

```
# first part to match any non-digit
# second part to match identical characters
df['col2'] = df.col1.mask(df.col1.str.contains(r'\D|^(.)\1*$'))
```

Output:

```
        col1       col2
0  086945159  086945159
1  549615853  549615853
2  589ac2546        NaN
3  GED456231        NaN
4  F56hy8W12        NaN
5  111111111        NaN
6  222222222        NaN
```

Comment: I guess I'm wrong in my comment. Learned something new today, thanks

Comment: what does `\D|^(.)\1*$` mean here?

Comment: @PeterChen see [explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/r6EWPK/1).

Comment: Is it possible to return `Nan` as `" "` or `""`?

Comment: chain with `fillna('')`?

Comment: Why `589ac2546` in col1 is not set up as NaN in col2 ?  Should we use str.contains() instead ?

Comment: @SeaBean good catch. Yes, that'd be a better choice. Thanks.